# Trouble having program terminate

Tags: java, infinite-loop, exit

I am doing a program for class.  Basically the program walks through some sales information for the day and prints a report at the end.

My only issue is that the program does not seem to exit at the end.  When i type "done" for the employee name it prints the report but the program loops back and continues to run asking for an employees year to date sales again.

I'm having trouble figuring out why the program is doing this.  If anyone could help point me towards what is causing it to loop instead of exit so that I can fix it that would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Project04Driver {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        Project04 app;
        app = new Project04();
        app.appMain();
    }
}

class Project04 {
private static DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat ("$#,###.00");
BufferedReader stdin;   
int trans, tCount;
double ytd, amount, empTotal, empBonus, totA, totF, totS, totSales, totYtd, hiTrans, ytdSales;
String date, hiEmp, name, type;
public void appMain() throws IOException {
    rptInit();
    displayHeader();
    getDate();
    while (!name.equalsIgnoreCase("Done")) {
        salesData();
    }
}

void rptInit() {
    name = "f";
    trans = 1;
    amount = totF = totA = totS = totSales = totYtd = hiTrans = ytdSales = 0;
    stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
}

void displayHeader() {
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Project #04 Solution");
    System.out.println("Written by Jordan Hawkes");
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("");
}

void getDate() throws IOException {
    System.out.print("Enter Date: ");
    date = stdin.readLine();
}

void salesData() throws IOException {
    System.out.print("Enter Name: ");
    name = stdin.readLine();
    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("done")) {
        rptOut();
        return;
    }

    System.out.print("Enter Year to Date Sales: ");
    ytd = Double.parseDouble(stdin.readLine());
    ytdSales = ytdSales + ytd;
    totYtd = totYtd + ytdSales;

    trans();

}

void trans() throws IOException {
    while (trans != 0) {
    System.out.print("Enter Transaction Number: ");
    trans = Integer.parseInt(stdin.readLine());

    if (trans == 0) {
        outputSalesData();
        empTotal = 0;
        empBonus = 0;
        ytdSales = 0;
        trans = 1;
        salesData();
    } else {
        System.out.print("Enter Transaction Type: ");
        type = stdin.readLine();
        System.out.print("Enter Transaction Amount: ");
        amount = Double.parseDouble(stdin.readLine());

        totSales = totSales + amount;
        totYtd = totYtd + amount;
        ytdSales = ytdSales + amount;
        empTotal = empTotal + amount;
        empBonus = empBonus + (amount * 0.05);

        outputUpdate();

        calcSalesData();
        tCount++;
    }
}
}

void calcSalesData() {
    if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("F")) {
        totF = totF + amount;
    }
    if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
        totA = totA + amount;
    }
    if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("S")) {
        totS = totS + amount;
    }

    hiTrans();
}

void hiTrans() {
    if (amount > hiTrans) {
        hiTrans = amount;
        hiEmp = name;
    }
}

void outputUpdate() {
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println(name + "'s Total Sales for Day: " + df2.format(empTotal));
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("");
}

void outputSalesData() {
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Employee Name: \t\t" + name);
    System.out.println("YTD Sales: \t\t" + df2.format(ytdSales));
    System.out.println("Employee Bonus: \t" + df2.format(empBonus));
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("");
}

void rptOut() {
     System.out.println("Total Food & Soft Drink Sales: \t" + df2.format(totF));
    System.out.println("Total Alcohol Sales: \t\t" + df2.format(totA));
    System.out.println("Total Sundries Sales: \t\t" + df2.format(totS));
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Total Sales for Day: \t\t" + df2.format(totSales));
    System.out.println("Total YTD: \t\t\t" + df2.format(totYtd));
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Highest Trans Amount: \t\t" + df2.format(hiTrans));
    System.out.println("Employee w/ Highest Trans: \t" + hiEmp);
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
    return;
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried stepping through with a debugger to see what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow the program to exit naturally, you should not call methods in a cycle, rather allow methods to exit and control the flow from the main loop.

Here is the redesigned approach:

The new main loop calls `salesData()` and `trans()` in a pair (assuming name is not "done")

```
while (!name.equalsIgnoreCase("Done")) {
    salesData();
    if (!name.equalsIgnoreCase("Done"))
        trans();
}
```

Now, method `salesData()` must not call `trans()`:

```
void salesData() throws IOException {
    System.out.print("Enter Name: ");
    name = stdin.readLine();
    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("done")) {
        rptOut();
        return;
    }
    // ... processing ...
 }
```

And also `trans()` must not call `salesData()`:

```
void trans() throws IOException {
   while (trans != 0) {
   System.out.print("Enter Transaction Number: ");
   trans = Integer.parseInt(stdin.readLine());

   if (trans == 0) {
     outputSalesData();
     empTotal = 0;
     empBonus = 0;
     ytdSales = 0;
   } else {
     System.out.print("Enter Transaction Type: ");
     type = stdin.readLine();
     System.out.print("Enter Transaction Amount: ");
     amount = Double.parseDouble(stdin.readLine());
     // ... processing ...
     outputUpdate();
     calcSalesData();
     tCount++;
   }
 }
}
```

Summary:  Now that methods `salesData()` and `trans()` do not call each other (they return naturally after completing the method), and since the control is now from the main loop, your application will exit as expected.

Comment: thank you, i see now that i was looping by calling the methods inside of each other.

Answer (score 1):

I cant comment directly in your question so i will put it in here. I think the problem lies were you call salesData():

-in appMain() you don't get a choice for that "Done" in your while loop so it never ends.

- my suggestion is making salesData to return a boolean once you are done with it that way you can say !boolean and return a true and that will end your while loop in appMain().

Hope this solves the issue!

Answer (score 1):

trans() and appMain() call salesData(). If salesData() is called by trans(), then a return in salesData() returns to trans(), which itself has a while-loop.

Answer (score 0):

In my stand-alone Java program, the following call does it:

```
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: when i add this at the end of the printed report (in rptOut()) then the program only prints the first line of the report ("total food & soft drink sales") and doesn't print the rest of it...

Comment: Ah - the output stream is not being flushed properly in your case. Call System.out.flush(), before the 'exit' is being called.

Comment: still only prints the first line for some reason...

I'm literally just adding:

System.out.flush();
System.exit(0);

right after the last print statement in the rptOut() method... is this correct?